# Printing files using adobe activex plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, printing, adobe, activex

I need the ability to print pdf file (which can be downloaded from a remote URL) in IE using abobe plugin. Before this, I used the java applet, but now it's impossible. I know that i could using javascript to access the some adobe activex object. Maybe someone has examples?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in [this question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501182/print-pdf-at-clientside-browser-without-opening-pdf):

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
timerID = setTimeout("exPDF.print();", 1000);
</script>
<body>
<object id="exPDF" type="application/pdf" data="111.pdf" width="100%" height="500"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The important part for you is that you can call the `print();` method on the object that is showing your PDF file.